# iOS - Reserve a minimum amount of free disk space for an app

Tags: ios, objective-c, diskspace

My app has to make sure that there is always a minimum amount (maybe 5-10 MB) of free disk space available, for it to operate correctly. I have to save important data to file, otherwise everything is going to be corrupted.

The main problem is: What if the user downloads my app and he had EXACTLY that amount of disk space free that he needed for the app (without my on first startup created data)

When he's now starting the app I try to do some initial setup stuff - here I have to write around 2-3 MB to file and this space must be free.

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: When exactly do you want to check this? On app startup? Why not just show an error message for not enough disk space for this app when running for the first space? You can't really _reserve_ memory, you can write to/allocate it so that no other app can use that part.

Comment: In Android, the app wont be installed (it will be downloaded) if there is insufficient space on the device. This is a feature of the platform, I imagine iOS does something similar.

Comment: But the App Store will only show the amount of disk spcae that my app needs for installing it. On first startup I need to write an additional 2-3 MB to disk and the App Store will allow the download, but then the 2-3 MB are not there. Of course I could show an error message. I was just wondering if one can set the amount of disk space needed higher than it really is.

Comment: can you include 3MB junk file with your app, that will be removed later?

Comment: @aandreev, no you can't. The only stuff you can include at download is content in the app bundle, and that's read-only in iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two things:

First, when your application starts, you can find out the available space using `NSFileManager.attributesForFilesystemofPath:`. If the amount of space is low (and 5 MB free is *really low*, you can warn the user and maybe even refuse to start actions in your app that require this available space.

Second, you could create a scratch file. If you know you need 5MB storage, then maybe you can allocate a 5MB file and use that file for your storage.

You don't specify what you need to store on disk but if it were for example one file then you could write this data over your 5MB scratch file instead of opening a new file.

This requires some extra bookkeeping, but you do get guaranteed space for your data.

Comment: I also thought about that, but was hoping there's a better solution. Thank you! I've got a few files to write to disk (and be sure it's always possible). Are you saying I could create a 5MB container file and then write into this thing? So I wouldn't have to delete my dummy file(s) if I need additional memory?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't. You will need to write your code to have an initial startup that checks to see if there is enough disk space to do your initial setup, and display an error if not.  I haven't tried to do this on iOS before so I'm not sure what the sandbox allows you to do off the top of my head. I'd have to go read up in the iOS file system docs. That's what I suggest you do.