# CoreData reserve space

Tags: swift, core-data, diskspace

Is there some way to reserve the disk space for `CoreData` object? I need to make sure that application will be constantly able to save data up to `1GB` of storage using `CoreData model`. I know I can check the free space before starting, but this is not enough. This process takes a lot of time, and I need to make sure, that space is reserved at all the time. `Model object` consists of an `array` with a lot of measurements that are being added while application is running.
I was thinking about creating a lot of empty objects with some flag telling if it's a real data or a placeholder, but it's taking way too long, and app crashes. Any way to preserve the disk space otherwise?

Comment: I don’t think there is any way to reserve space, neither in Core Data nor in the OS. But maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890012/ios-reserve-a-minimum-amount-of-free-disk-space-for-an-app) question can be helpful

Comment: iOS doesn't have any option to reserve disk space, whether or not you use Core Data.